# Formatter not found error for python logging

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am trying to configure Python logging using a logging.conf file and I can't seem to get it working.

I have the following directory structure:

```
myproject
|_logging
  |_conf
    |_logging.conf
  |_logs
    |_<saved logs>
|_subdir
  |_subsubdir
    |_subsubsubdir
      |_python_script
```

I am trying to load the logging.conf file in "python_script" as follows:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

# Load the logging configuration from file
RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_LOGGING_DIR = '\logging\conf\logging.conf'
ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_LOGGING_CONF = os.getcwd()+RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_LOGGING_DIR

fileConfig(RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_LOGGING_DIR, disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

This script fails on the "fileConfig()" line with the following error:

```
 fileConfig(RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_LOGGING_DIR, disable_existing_loggers=False)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\config.py", line 72, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\config.py", line 105, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\config.py", line 72, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\config.py", line 105, in _create_formatters    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser.py", line 965, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

My logging.conf file is as follows:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,myLogger

[handlers]
keys=mylogHandler

[formatters]
keys=mylogFormatter

[handler_mylogHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=mylogFormatter
args=('logging/logs/logfile.log', 'midnight', 1, 5,)

[formatter_mylogFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%H:%M:%S

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handler=mylogHandler
formatter=mylogFormatter

[logger_myLogger]
level=DEBUG
handler=mylogHandler
formatter=mylogFormatter
```

I have tried to use both absolute and relative paths and neither are working. I've also tried to put the logging.conf file in the same directory as the python script I am trying to load it in and this didn't work either.

I've tried to set the disable_existing_loggers to both True/False but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so after 2 days of struggling with this I was finally able to fix it. If anyone else comes across this problem, I was able to fix it by simple renaming my "logging.conf" file to "logging.ini". I have no idea why or how this worked but I'm not going to look into it any further.

Comment: Are you sure your code is still the same and you only changed the filename? This sounds kinda odd...

Comment: Yep I am certain of this. I just tested it again to me sure. My code ran and logged just fine with logging.ini but failed as soon as I renamed it to logging.conf.